# DateTime and ParseExact not working properly

Tags: c#, asp.net, jquery

I am using AJAX and  sending certain data:

```
  var eventtype = parseInt(record.<%= CEO.FieldEvaluator.GetEvaluatorByDId("EVENT_TYPE_ID").GetFieldDataFieldId()%>);
   var begindate = parseInt(record.<%= CEO.FieldEvaluator.GetEvaluatorByDId("BeginDate").GetFieldDataFieldId()%>);
   var enddate = parseInt(record.<%= CEO.FieldEvaluator.GetEvaluatorByDId("EndDate").GetFieldDataFieldId()%>);

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST", url: "Data.aspx/CheckInsertRecord",
            data: "{EventType:'" + eventtype + "',BeginDate:'" + begindate + "'," +
                   "EndDate:'" + enddate+"' }",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8", dataType: "json",
            success: function (msg) {
            alert(msg.d);

            }
        });
```

In the code behind:

```
  CultureInfo provider = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;

    DateTime bd = DateTime.ParseExact(BeginDate,"MM/DD/YYYY", provider);
    DateTime ed = DateTime.ParseExact(EndDate, "MM/DD/YYYY", provider);
```

However when I run it i get an error saying

```
  "String was not recognized as a valid Datetime"
```

Can u please help me in getting rid of this.

Or is there any other way to convert string to a DateTime?

Comment: Are begindate  and endDate in the MM/DD/YYYY format?

Comment: Yes. It is in MM/DD/YYYY format

Answer (score 1):

In .NET, a correct [custom date/time format string](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx) for a date string like "01/01/2011" is `"MM/dd/yyyy"`

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
DateTime bd = DateTime.ParseExact(BeginDate,"MM/dd/yyyy", provider);
DateTime ed = DateTime.ParseExact(EndDate, "MM/dd/yyyy", provider);
```

or

```
DateTime bd = DateTime.ParseExact(BeginDate,"M/d/yyyy", provider);
DateTime ed = DateTime.ParseExact(EndDate, "M/d/yyyy", provider);
```

Comment: @Nishanth I tested `DateTime bd = DateTime.ParseExact("12/31/2010","MM/DD/YYYY", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);` and `DateTime bd = DateTime.ParseExact("12/31/2010","MM/dd/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);` and I did not get the exception with the second format.

Comment: @Nishanth what does BeginDate string look like?

Comment: I updated the code....... it is actually something user enters from a calendar and it looks like 6/31/2011

Comment: @Nishanth  `6/31/2011`  in not a valid date. there's only 30 days in June. Also `"M/d/yyyy"` looks more appropriate for your context.

Comment: K. I did not try to add it .. I just wrote it as a example

Comment: @Nishanth I just tried `6/30/2011` with 'M/d/yyyy' and it works for me, as you can **[see here](http://ideone.com/PPgmH)**. Your problem could be somewhere else?